# OpenGL id value guarantee

Tags: opengl, resources

I am confronted with the fact that sometimes my OpenGL Context gets re-created and my initialization needs to be redone to re-initialize the re-created OpenGL Context.
Right now I am not using many elements, but I mentioned that the IDs (or names or whatchacallthem) that I receive from glGenX are always the same as long as I call the functions in the same order: The first texture I create gets ID 1, the second ID 2 etc. etc.

Is this guaranteed? Because when it is, my internal organization of those OpenGL elements does not need to be re-done, as even though the OpenGL context is another, a reference to texture ID 4 will always point at the correct texture as long as that texture gets re-loaded into the GPU 4th in row?

Comment: Why does your OpenGL context get re-created? There's not a single valid situation why this should happen in a program, except for if you want to tear down and recreate everything. OpenGL contexts can be reused between windows (driver bugs may of course prevent this). I know that some frameworks, like SDL-1 are prone to destroy contexts when the window gets resized or similar. If that's your problem, switch the framework or fix that issue.

Comment: I directly use JOGL and I want to have a Window that is resizable, can change it's fullscreen mode and it's decoration dynamically. Since at least one of these things is not possible in either SWING or NEWT, I use SWING, but to change decoration there I need to dispose the window, destroying the context. Also it is said that the context might be destroyed when changing screens or when you do other things that you might be accustomed to having your screen "flicker" for a second (for a lack of a better explanation)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, I have never seen a guarantee that the generation of object names will produce the same result each time. The language for the `glGen*()` calls always sounds like this:

> returns *n* previous unused [..] object names

It never says anything more about how these object names are constructed.

Now, in reality, if you're calling everything in exactly the same sequence, it seems very likely that you're going to get the same names. Software tends to be deterministic in cases like this. But relying on it still sounds like a bad idea to me. It will be one of these things that will probably work for the longest time, and then come back and bite you when you least expect it at the most unfortunate time (like the day before you plan to ship, or after you already shipped).

I don't think this is strictly within the scope of your question, but just to make sure that you're not making any false assumptions: You definitely can't expect the names to be sequential. They are on some platforms/vendors, but not on others. There's also no valid expectation on whether different object types use different names, or if they use the same values. For example, if you call `glGenTextures()` to create a texture name, and `glGenBuffers()` to create a buffer name, you could get the same value for the two names.

Also, just to avoid possible misunderstandings: Even if you assume that you already know the names that are going to be generated, you still need to call the `glGen*()` functions to generate the names if you use the OpenGL Core Profile. It used to be legal to just use any values you wanted for object names, but that's not legal anymore in modern OpenGL. Or in the words of the spec, from the Removed Features appendix:

> Application-generated object names - the names of all object types, such as buffer, query, and texture objects, must be generated using the corresponding Gen* commands. Trying to bind an object name not returned by a Gen* command will result in an INVALID_OPERATION error.

Comment: Nice answer! Btw, from what I understand, if `sizeof(GLuint) == sizeof(void*)` an implementation might as well return a pointer to some internal structure disguised as a `GLuint`, no? Or is there any requirement that the ids be sequential numbers (like indexes into an array)?

Comment: Yes, they don't have to be sequential. I mention that around the middle of the answer. That's not only theory, you sometimes see interesting numbers for ids on some devices. In the case I'm thinking of, they don't look like pointers either, but I can't think of a good reason why returning a 32-bit pointer would be illegal. Not sure if it would be practical, though. You have to be able to detect it as an error if an incoming id is invalid. If you treat them as pointers, you would crash if somebody passes a garbage id as an argument.